# Is that can be possible ? same Store Procedure returns value in sql server 2014 and in Sql server 2012 dont

Tags: database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, server, sql-server-2014

I have same Database on Server and same on Local.
Same tables same stored procedure, same records.
In local PC database using SQL server 2014 management studio,
and at Server PC database using SQL server 2012 management studio.

Executing on **SQL server 2012** Stored procedure executes successfully but **does not do any operation on table's data.** 
Executing on **SQL server 2014** Stored procedure executes successfully and **all operations are done successfully with table's data.**

can it be possible ?
and why?

Comment: Yes but you're not giving us any clues. Are you certain they are identical. Open the database properties and compare them carefully. Are columns the same collation? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on each database.

Comment: it was working before 2 day and now stoped working, Tried to clean Local cache from server but it not solved my problem.

Comment: You need to be thorough and consistent in your investigations. There's still nothing for us to go on. What did you get from the version query?

Comment: hey there, Problem is solved. Thanks for the replying.. Issue was in data processing... excel sheet was containing information NULL in the column and after importing to the database it was putting single quote before and after NULL so it was not returning result. Thanks for the cooperation.

Comment: So what you're saying is the records were  _not_ the same

Comment: The excel sheet which i was uploading to the database, it was in correct format(Column wise). But problem was that -if the column which have NULL value than SQL Server will take it as 'NULL' (string format) --(it is because of SSIS package, I am using it to import excel file data to SQL SERVER DB)-- so it will be not considered as a proper value for Stored procedure to perform desired operation on that data.

Comment: Solution for that SSIS package which making excel's cell's NULL value into 'NULL' value -- Must use a derived column transformation  function. For replacing that 'NULL' value to the Blank or Null to the database when Importing.